# File Chooser Dialog not showing (GTK4/Rust)

Tags: rust, gtk4

I just started coding with Rust and I want to make a linux application using Gtk4.
I'm trying to implement a FileChooserDialog following the Text_viewer Example from gtk-rs github but the window is not showing off and I'm not sure what I'm really doing wrong.

```
const APP_ID: &str = "org.bht.pgp_manager";
fn main() {
    // create a new appliation
    let app = Application::new(
        Some(APP_ID),
        Default::default(),
    );
    // connect to activate signal of app
    app.connect_activate(build_ui);
    // run the application
    app.run();
}

pub fn build_ui(app: &Application){
    let gtk_box = gtk::Box::builder()
        .orientation(Orientation::Vertical)
        .build();

    let window = ApplicationWindow::builder()
        .default_height(100)
        .default_width(300)
        .title("My GTK Application")
        .child(&gtk_box)
        .build();
    
    window.set_application(Some(app));
        
    let import_button = Button::builder()
        .name("import_certificate")
        .label("Import Certificate")
        .margin_bottom(12)
        .margin_end(12)
        .margin_start(12)
        .margin_top(12)
        .build();
 
    import_button.connect_clicked(glib::clone!(@weak window => move |_| {
        eprintln!("we are here at the import button");
        
        let file_chooser = FileChooserDialog::new(
            Some("Import File"),
            Some(&window),
            FileChooserAction::Open,
            &[("Open", ResponseType::Ok), ("Cancel", ResponseType::Cancel)],
        );
        file_chooser.show();
    }));

    gtk_box.append(&import_button);
    
    window.show();  
}
```

Comment: I've just tried your code and it works for me. There is an error in console: "Unsupported modifier, resource creation failed." that I don't know where it comes from. But the window is shown and the button opens the file chooser.

Comment: @rodrigo now it's working but I'm not getting the error message. I didn't change the code or anything but it worked and I don't have any explanation for it ...